# Siteminder server and GUI download

Tags: single-sign-on, siteminder

I tried to download siteminder trial version based on [THIS LINK](http://www.coreblox.com/2010/01/quick-guide-to-installing-siteminder-wam-r12-sp2/).But while googling somewhere it says siteminder is not free even for development like Oracle(Express Edition).Please clarify my doubt about this.If trial version is available please direct to me there.Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Reddymails please check this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CA Single Sign On (formerly CA SiteMinder) has a "demo" mode where no license is required. However, I believe there is no "free" usage of CA SSO available for development (or at least there hasn't been in the past). You must either get it through your CA Account Exec or have a valid login to the CA Support portal.

Comment: Could you give me the link for them, only I could get as demo is pdf even after as a registered user.This is the link I used http://www.ca.com/us/collateral/data-sheets/na/ca-single-sign-on.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The Downloads page for SiteMinder (CA Single Sign On) typically contains an older version than the latest available (Service Pack/CR).  The CA SiteMinder Hotfix URL contains the latest version of all CA SiteMinder products.  I would recommend downloading the installation files from the Hotfix URL instead of the downloads page.

http://www.ca.com/us/services-support/ca-support/ca-support-online/product-content/recommended-reading/technical-document-index/ca-single-sign-on-hotfix-cumulative-release-index.html